# How to move time series forecast backwards in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Predicting future is just normal coding but is there any way that I can move the predicting interval backwards to check if the forecast interval is too narrow or too wide?

Here is the sample code:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(log(dat1$V2), c(1, 1, 1), include.constant=T)
plot(forecast(fit,h=30),include=100)
```

[image]

I guess I can just cut the original data set in a certain time point and fit the cut file again but is there anyway more handy?

Comment: @FatihAkici, I actually tried  `h=c(1000:1030)` and `h=-30`, but it didn't work.

Comment: @FatihAkici Maybe you miss understood my question. I was trying to move my forecast interval from 1280 like what Minitab can do so I can comparing my forecasting trend and the real trend after 1280.